# Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the 'highest' function. It must be > 0

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to draw a horizontal line over the candles, only when the RSI value is under 30.
so I used "ta.barssince" to count the numbers of candles, then, I used it as a length in "ta.highest" then I plot, below is the script:

`RSI=ta.rsi(close,14)`
`var float highUsePivot= na`  
`Candles := ta.barssince(RSI > 30)`
`highUsePivot := ta.highest(high, Candles)`
`plot(highUsePivot, color=color.yellow)` 
However, I still getting this message shown to me:

Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the 'highest' function. It must be > 0.

Can please let me know what's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial candles there will be no values of rsi and you will get nan value in Candles variable. So you will have to reset nan values to 1 using nz function. Also for some candles it is possible to get value as 0 when same candle rsi is less than 30. So you will have to set Candles value to 1 wherever it is 0. So final working code will be as below.

```
//@version=5 
indicator(title='EMA', overlay=true)

var Candles=0
RSI=ta.rsi(close,14) 
var float highUsePivot= na   
Candles := nz(ta.barssince(RSI > 30),1)
if Candles==0
    Candles:=1
highUsePivot := ta.highest(high, Candles) 
plot(highUsePivot, color=color.yellow)
```